# Sound Menu options are disabled

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, indicator-sound

Accidentally I have removed the pulse audio from my Ubuntu 12.04. But after that I am unable to use the sound applet options of changing output, input volumes and unable to test the output speakers. Help me to get rid of this issue. Also after that the sound indicator also disappeared from indicator pane.

Comment: Your best guess is to re- install the `pulseaudio` and `ubuntu-desktop` packages.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall pulseaudio again and restart the service.

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
pulseaudio --start
```